# how to change all backbone models attribute

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am new to Backbone, Please help me out with this problem.

my model looks like this:

```
var optionItem = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var itemOne = new optionItem({price: 200});
var itemTwo = new optionItem({price: 300});
var itemThree = new optionItem({price: 400});
```

My Collection looks like this:

```
var optionClass = Backbone.Collection.extend({});  
var firstOptionClass = new optionClass([itemOne, itemTwo, itemThree]);
```

the requirement is to create 3 radio buttons, and showing the price of all 3 items. when user clicks any radio button, the selected item price will change to "include in price", other 2 items will show price difference instead. for example if I click on itemOne, itemTwo will have price "+100" instead of showing 300.

I know how to create views for model and collection to display the original information, but have no idea how to write the click event function...Currently I have the event function in the model view, but cant access to another 2 models price attribute to perform math, should I move the event function to the collection view?

Please Help, Thank you in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to approach this, but one thing to keep in mind is that every model maintains a reference to the collection it belongs to. So in your view, `this.model` has a `this.model.collection` property you can use to access the collection if necessary. That said, I would probably use a collection view to handle the display of collection related information to prevent the item view from violating the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) When one of the options is selected, have the selected model trigger an event. Model events bubble up to the collection, and you can have the collection view listen for that event on the collection to update the "difference" values of the other options.

Comment: I got it work!! I put event function in the model view, and use this.model.collection.each() to calculate the price. Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

Click Even function should be in Backbone.View

And as you need to access multiple model to get price. Your event function should also be in Backbone.View Controller instead of Model Class.

Hope it helps,